# Lotus Notes @For Loop in a XML output

Tags: xml, for-loop, lotus-notes

I got the following code, which - on the surface - seems rather simple, but it does not work.
I somehow cannot get the for loop to work.

Anyways, any input is appreciated:

```
_attachments_raw:=@AttachmentNames;
_attachments_count := @Elements(_attachments_raw);

@if(_attachments_count<>0;
"<attachments>"+
@For(i :=1;
i <= @Attachments;
i := i + 1;
"<attachment no=\""+@Text(i)+"\">"+
@Text(i)
+"</attachment>")
+"</attachments>"
;"")
```

The final code should actually be like this:

```
_attachments_raw:=@AttachmentNames;
_attachments_count := @Elements(_attachments_raw);

@if(_attachments_count<>0;
"<attachments>"+
@For(i :=1;
i <= @Attachments;
i := i + 1;
"<attachment no=\""+@Text(i)+"\">"+
_attachmentUrlPrefix + @Text(_attachments_raw[i])+
+"</attachment>")
+"</attachments>"
;"")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What do you expect to get?  What do you actually get?  Also, I'm not clear on why you've given two code samples? Are you saying that they both don't work?

Comment: I want to loop through a list of attachments and the output is basically an XML file. The second piece of code is what I want finally, but the first one does not work either. I try to do it step by step.

Comment: So what is the XML that you want, and what is the XML that you get?

Comment: Solved it, the answer below worked well. Had to do some string manipulation but overall worked well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a variable, as your Text is overwritten in each For- Loop and only the last element is returned. A working example would be (although the usage of _attachment_count and @Attachments in this code is not necessary, as both have the same value):

```
_attachments_raw:=@AttachmentNames;
_attachments_count := @Elements(_attachments_raw);


@For(i :=1; i <= @Attachments; i := i + 1;
_attachmentElements := _attachmentElements + "<attachment no=\""+@Text(i)+"\">"+
_attachmentUrlPrefix + @Text(_attachments_raw[i])+
"</attachment>"
);

@if(    _attachments_count<>0;
        "<attachments>" + _attachmentElements + "</attachments>"
        ;"" )
```

Comment: I get an error: "not well formed". There was one plus too many here `@Text(_attachments_raw[i])++"</attachment>"` but that didnt solve the error.

Comment: "not well formed": Does that mean an error when trying to read the xml or when trying to save the formula?

Comment: It's in the XML output. You might be German, and if so, the error message: `XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: nicht wohlgeformt`

Comment: The problem occurs due to the following, because without the code it works: `+@Text(_attachments_raw[i])`

Comment: If the error is "malformed", then check the output... I guess, that the attachmentnames contain invalid characters, that's why it is malformed. This has nothing to do with the formula, as it builds "valid" xml... Just view the xml in a text- Editor (I recommend Notepad++, as it will tell you, where the error in your code is)

Comment: Yes, the input was corrupt.